# AJAX call updates data attribute, but reading attribute returns pre-AJAX value

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have an AJAX call that successfully updates the data-attribute of a div. However, when I read the data-attribute using

```
matchupid = $('#matchupID').data('matchupid')
```

after an AJAX update (which successfully changes the attribute when I inspect the element using DevTools), it returns the original matchupID, instead of the new ID input by the AJAX call. Any idea why this would be happening? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I think I fixed it. I was updating the data using

```
.attr('data-matchupID', $('#matchupID').data('matchupid'))
```

and reading the data using

```
.data('matchupID')
```

Should that make a difference?

Comment: can u create a jsfiddle with your issue??

Comment: Where is the code that changes the data?

Comment: @iJay, I added some additional info above

Comment: @musa, I added some additionl info above

Comment: I don't know if they're case sensitive, did you try using the same case for both. Also you should use `.data()` to update the value instead of `.attr()`